# Why does a Rake task in a loop execute only once?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have rails application that connects to multiple databases. I wrote custom rake task that looks like this:

```
task :migrate_accounts_schema => [:environment] do |t|
  users = User.find :all, :conditions => ["state = 2"], :order => "id asc"
  users.each do |user|            
    if user.state == 2
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        :adapter  => "postgresql",
        :host     => user.database_host,
        :port     => user.database_port,
        :username => user.subdomain,
        :password => "#{user.database_password}",
        :database => user.database_name
      )
      Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that task executes db:migrate only for users[0] user (first user in collection) and there is no errors, just stoppes silently...

Here's output from rake --trace

```
** Invoke app:migrate_accounts_schema (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute app:migrate_accounts_schema    
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:dump
** Invoke db:migrate
```

I have no idea why the rest of users don't get migrated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I forgot the exact internals but the way Rake works is that `invoke` will only execute each task if it needs to (in other words once).

Try calling execute on subsequent calls:

`Rake::Task["db:migrate"].execute`

The first time through the loop you'll need `invoke` as it invokes the prerequisites first.

Comment: This seems very counter-intuitive to me. Any ideas why they made it like this?

Comment: Wasted an hour on this — couldn't figure out why the task wasn't called multiple times in a unit test. Thanks!

Comment: If the task takes arguments pass them as a hash: `Rake::Task["db:migrate"].execute(arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2, ...)`

Answer (score 26):

I found answer in the Rake source:

http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Task.html#M000115

It says that you have to

*Reenable the task, allowing its tasks to be executed if the task is invoked again.*

e.g. I used this recently on my project this way:

```
# db/seed.rb
Rake::Task['catalog:destroy'].invoke

files = Dir.glob("private/catalog/*").sort
files.each do |file|
  next unless File.extname(file) == '.xlsx'
  puts file.split('/').last
  Rake::Task['catalog:upload'].invoke(file)
  Rake::Task['catalog:upload'].reenable
  puts
end
```

So I run rake catalog:upload[some_file] every loop.

Hope this helps.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290119/3082929

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the technically correct answer (`#reenable`, not just `#execute`)