# How do I execute Rake tasks with arguments multiple times?

Tags: ruby, rake

It's not possible to `invoke` the same rake task from within a loop [more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822020/rake-task-in-loop-executes-only-first-task). But, I want to be able to call `rake first` and loop through an array and invoke `second` on each iteration with different arguments. Since `invoke` only gets executed the first time around, I tried to use `execute`, but [Rake::Task#execute](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Task.html#M000120) doesn't use the splat (*) operator and only takes a single argument.

```
desc "first task"
task :first do 
  other_arg = "bar"
  [1,2,3,4].each_with_index do |n,i|
    if i == 0 
      Rake::Task["foo:second"].invoke(n,other_arg)
    else
      # this doesn't work
      Rake::Task["foo:second"].execute(n,other_arg)
    end
  end
end

task :second, [:first_arg, :second_arg] => :prerequisite_task do |t,args|
  puts args[:first_arg]
  puts args[:second_arg]
  # ...
end
```

One hack around it is to put the arguments to `execute` into an array and in `second` examine the structure of args, but that seems, well, hackish. Is there another (better?) way to accomplish what I'd like to do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use Rake::Task#reenable to allow it to be invoked again.

```
desc "first task"
task :first do 
  other_arg = "bar"
  [1,2,3,4].each_with_index do |n,i|
    if i == 0 
      Rake::Task["second"].invoke(n,other_arg)
    else
      # this does work
      Rake::Task["second"].reenable
      Rake::Task["second"].invoke(n,other_arg)
    end
  end
end

task :second, [:first_arg, :second_arg]  do |t,args|
  puts args[:first_arg]
  puts args[:second_arg]
  # ...
end
```

$ rake first

```
1
bar
2
bar
3
bar
4
bar
```

Answer (score 4):

The `execute` function asks for a [Rake::TaskArguments](http://rake.rubyforge.org/Rake/TaskArguments.html) as a parameter, this is why it only accepts one argument.

[You could use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19690760/2298505)

```
stuff_args = {:match => "HELLO", :freq => '100' }
Rake::Task["stuff:sample"].execute(Rake::TaskArguments.new(stuff_args.keys, stuff_args.values))
```

However there is another difference between invoke and execute, execute doesn't run the :prerequisite_task when invoke does this first, so invoke and reenable or execute doesn't have exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW this might help someone so I'll post it.

I wanted to be able to run one command from the CLI to run one Rake task multiple times (each time with new arguments, but that's not important).

Example:

```sh
rake my_task[x] my_task[y] my_task[z]
```

However, since Rake sees all `my_task` as the same task regardless of the args, it will only invoke the first time `my_task[x]` and will not invoke `my_task[y]` and `my_task[z]`.

Using the `Rake::Task#reenable` method as mentioned in the other answers, I wrote a `reenable` Rake task which you can position to run after a task to allow it to run again.

Result:

```sh
rake my_task[x] reenable[my_task] my_task[y] reenable[my_task] my_task[z]
```

I wouldn't say this is ideal but it works for my case.

#### `reenable` Rake task source:

```rb
task :reenable, [:taskname] do |_task, args|
  Rake::Task[args[:taskname]].reenable
  Rake::Task[:reenable].reenable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, it's quite easy to understand you just need to loop you bash command.

```
task :taskname, [:loop] do |t, args|
        $i = 0
        $num = args.loop.to_i
        while $i < $num  do
        sh 'your bash command''
        $i +=1
        end
    end
```