# testing rake tasks with Rspec is not accepting arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake, rake-task

I am trying to write a Rspec test for one of my rake task, according to [this post by Stephen Hagemann](http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/how-i-test-rake-tasks).

`lib/tasks/retry.rake`:

```
namespace :retry do

  task :message, [:message_id] => [:environment] do |t, args|
    TextMessage.new.resend!(args[:message_id])
  end
end
```

`spec/tasks/retry_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'rake'

describe 'retry namespace rake task' do
  describe 'retry:message' do
    before do
      load File.expand_path("../../../lib/tasks/retry.rake", __FILE__)
      Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
    end

    it 'should call the resend action on the message with the specified message_id' do
      message_id = "5"
      expect_any_instance_of(TextMessage).to receive(:resend!).with message_id
      Rake::Task["retry:message[#{message_id}]"].invoke
    end

  end
end
```

However, when I run this test, I am getting the following error:

```
Don't know how to build task 'retry:message[5]'
```

On the other hand, when I run the task with no argument as:

```
Rake::Task["retry:message"].invoke
```

I am able to get the rake task invoked, but the test fails as there is no `message_id`.

What is wrong with the way I'm passing in the argument into the rake task?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12948485/4330954) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/825832/4330954), the following are some ways of calling rake tasks with arguments:

```
Rake.application.invoke_task("my_task[arguments]")
```

or

```
Rake::Task["my_task"].invoke(arguments)
```

On the other hand, I was calling the task as:

```
Rake::Task["my_task[arguments]"].invoke
```

Which was a Mis combination of the above two methods.

A big `thank you` to Jason for his contribution and suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, rake tasks shouldn't *do* things, they should only *call* things. I never write specs for my rake tasks, only the things they call.

Since your rake task appears to be a one-liner (as rake tasks should be, IMO), I wouldn't write a spec for it. If it were more than one line, I would move that code somewhere else to make it a one-liner.

But if you insist on writing a spec, maybe try this: `Rake::Task["'retry:message[5]'"].invoke` (added single quotes).

Comment: > rake tasks shouldn't do things, they should only call things. I never write specs for my rake tasks, only the things they call. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Update from year 2023**

You can try like below

**Rake::Task['retry:message'].execute(Rake::TaskArguments.new([:message_id], ['900000']))**