# How to run rake tasks from console?

Tags: console, rake

I want to invoke my rake task from console. Is it doable? if yes, how to do so?

I tried this on console:

```rb
require 'rake'
Rake::Task['my_task'].invoke
```

but it give me this error:

```
RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task
```

it's like the rake cannot found the task.

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Edit: I am using rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Running your Rake tasks requires two steps:

1. Loading **Rake**
2. Loading your **Rake tasks**

You are missing the second step.

Normally this is done in the Rakefile, but you have to do it manually here:

```rb
require 'rake'
Rails.application.load_tasks # <-- MISSING LINE
Rake::Task['my_task'].invoke
```

Comment: For more options please consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks

Comment: You might want to note the difference between saying `.invoke` and `.execute`, if you need to run the task several times (such as a data sanity checker with an app that takes too long to start up) then you'll want to `.execute` the task.

Comment: If you need to pass arguments, do it in the invoke method: `.invoke(arg1, arg2,...)`

Comment: Is this the best approach when needing to run a rake task from within the app itself? (for example I will run `db:seed` each time the test suite runs to reseed the database. I used the above code and it works, just wondering if it's best practice or if there's some other way?

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way to do it is to run %x[*command*] from the irb. I'm not sure if what you want to achieve though.

```
%x[rake db:migrate]
```

**EDIT:** I highly recommend to use `.invoke` as Daniel says in the accepted answer.

Comment: the problem is, rake doesn't seem to recognize my task. any idea why?

Comment: it works perfectly @garno ! sorry I know it's been a year and suddenly I am running into the same need.

Comment: You can also surround it in back ticks if you'd like.

Comment: This is slow because it has to spin up a new process and instantiating your Rails app again. `invoke` is better and more efficient.

Answer (score 17):

The easy way is:

```rb
Rails.application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['my_task'].invoke
```

Comment: This is not only the easy way but also means you're not spinning up a new process and instantiating your Rails app again. Easy _AND_ Fast!

Answer (score 7):

I am using `rails 5.x.x`, and was in the need the do the same form `rails console`.
I have create rake task here-

```
app/lib/task_to_execute.rake
```

Here is the command worked for me-

Load `Rails.application.load_tasks`

```
Rake::Task['task_to_execute:task_name'].invoke
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that if you are in the rails console via `rails c` you can just call/run the rake task method by `irb(main):001:0> TaskClassName.new.my_task`

Answer (score 0):

If you do *not* use Rails:

```ruby
require 'rake'

rake = Rake::Application.new
rake.load_rakefile

Rake::Task['some_task_from_rakefile'].execute
```

Also

- `Rake::Task.tasks` returns the list of all loaded tasks
- `Rake::Application::DEFAULT_RAKEFILES` holds the default lookup file names.

P.S. I am aware that the author asked for Rails solution, but I couldn't find a better place where to put this.