# Is it possible to make an interactive Rake task?

Tags: rake

I want to run a Rake task that asks the user for input.

I know that I can supply input on the command line, but I want to ask the user if they are *sure* they want to proceed with a particular action in case they mistyped one of the values supplied to the Rake task.

Comment: Look into [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor) instead for interactive tasks. It's vastly superior to Rake, and it comes with Rails, so you already have it without installing anything.

Comment: @meagar just ran into this today and am stuck, did you ever figure that out? I'm on a Mac with zsh . . .

Comment: Just figured it out -- it apparently was related to the Rails zsh plugin. When I removed that plugin, restarted zsh, then re-added it the problem disappeared . . .

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Something like this might work

```
task :action do
  STDOUT.puts "I'm acting!"
end

task :check do
  STDOUT.puts "Are you sure? (y/n)"
  input = STDIN.gets.strip
  if input == 'y'
    Rake::Task["action"].reenable
    Rake::Task["action"].invoke
  else
    STDOUT.puts "So sorry for the confusion"
  end
end
```

Task reenabling and invoking from [How to run Rake tasks from within Rake tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks/1290119#1290119)

Comment: any idea when this code would show "^M" when the enter key is pressed after typing "no" ??

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example without using another task.

```
task :solve_earth_problems => :environment do    
  STDOUT.puts "This is risky. Are you sure? (y/n)"

  begin
    input = STDIN.gets.strip.downcase
  end until %w(y n).include?(input)

  if input != 'y'
    STDOUT.puts "So sorry for the confusion"
    return
  end

  # user accepted, carry on
  Humanity.wipe_out!
end
```

Answer (score 5):

A handy feature for user input is to put it in a `do..while` loop, to only continue when a user has supplied valid input. Ruby doesn't explicitly have this construct, but you can achieve the same thing with `begin` and `until`. That would add to the accepted answer as follows:

```
task :action do
  STDOUT.puts "I'm acting!"
end

task :check do
  # Loop until the user supplies a valid option
  begin
    STDOUT.puts "Are you sure? (y/n)"
    input = STDIN.gets.strip.downcase
  end until %w(y n).include?(input)

  if input == 'y'
    Rake::Task["action"].reenable
    Rake::Task["action"].invoke
  else
    # We know at this point that they've explicitly said no, 
    # rather than fumble the keyboard
    STDOUT.puts "So sorry for the confusion"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also wrap this up in a service class so it can be unit-tested and used across your rake tasks:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class RakeConfirmDialog
  def initialize(question)
    @question = "#{question} (y/n)"
    @answer = "".inquiry
  end

  def confirm!
    prompt until (proceed? || abort?)

    respond

    proceed?
  end

  private

  def prompt
    STDOUT.puts @question

    @answer = STDIN.gets.strip.downcase.inquiry
  end

  def respond
    STDOUT.puts proceed? ? "Proceeding." : "Aborting."
  end

  def proceed?
    @answer.y?
  end

  def abort?
    @answer.n?
  end
end
```

Then use it like so in your task:

```
next unless RakeConfirmDialog.new(
  "About to close the Hellmouth forever. Are you sure you want 'Buffy the Vampire Slayer' to have a happy ending?"
).confirm!
```