# How can I declare this dependency in my Rakefile?

Tags: ruby, build, rake

I'm trying to build a static lib, whose name I only get after I process some files. I have something like this:

```
task :lib,:config do |t,args|
  # ... do some processing here, get a string representing the 
  # fullpath of the lib. Imaging libname contains a.lib
  file libname => object_files
end
```

But, of course, since I don't know the name of the dependency when the task gets ran, the code that should build a.lib doesn't get executed. I tried to do like this:

```
task :lib,:config do |t,args|
  # ... do some processing here, get a string representing the 
  # fullpath of the lib. Imaging libname contains a.lib
  file libname => object_files
  task :lib => [libname]
end
```

To add this as a dependency, but it doesn't work. I have it like this now, and it works:

```
task :lib,:config do |t,args|
  # ... do some processing here, get a string representing the 
  # fullpath of the lib. Imaging libname contains a.lib
  file libname => object_files
  Rake.application[libname].invoke
end
```

but I feel it's too ugly. Is there a better way to declare this dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rake::Task[libname].invoke
```

That looks slightly nicer to my eyes, i don't think there is a way of excuting a rake task within a rake task other than calling .execute or .invoke.

Comment: I think they are equivalent. So, probably, it's the only way.

Comment: Careful, they are not quite equivalent. #execute will *always* execute the task, even if it's already been invoked whereas #invoke will execute it only if it hasn't yet been invoked. Additionally, #execute won't execute prerequisites whereas #invoke will.

Answer (score 3):

I think this thread already has the best answer: [How to run Rake tasks from within Rake tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/577944/516450)