# How can I make an alias both cd and run a script or run a script in a non-home directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, constants, class-variables

How can I make an alias either run a script in another directory or both cd and run the script?

I have commands in my `.bashrc` file to `cd /home/myname/my_dir`

and also

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

when I am in our app directory (that contains the /script subdirectory).

I have not been able to put either put the directory in the rake command or have the alias do a cd and then the rake command that it currently does.

For instance I attempted `rake /home/my_dir/out_code_directory/sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=test` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alias rakesolr='cd dir; rake sunspot:solr:start; cd -'
```

works for me (in bash). Does that do what you need?

[ Ahh, **semicolon !**  Michael.]

Comment: Accepted and +1 for the cd - to go back!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can you edit your rake task ?
Or you can make a new task that do a Dir.chdir and then execute the task wanted.

Edit : resource about execute a task within another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a small bash script that cds then executes the script and have that run via an aliased command?