# Executing db:test:prepare from another rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to execute `rake db:test:prepare` from another task.

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :populate do
    desc "Seed development database"
    task development: :environment do
      puts "Kill local server"
      %x{ ps xauwww | grep -i --regex="[t]hin" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill }
      puts "Resetting development database"
      Rake::Task['db:reset'].execute
      puts "Migrating development database"
      Rake::Task['db:migrate'].execute
      puts "Populating development database"
      Rake::Task['db:populate'].execute
      puts "Pepare test database"
      Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].execute
      puts "Start local server"
      system 'thin -d start'
    end
   …
end
```

Using invoke instead of execute doesn't help. It seems to work fine if I define it by itself:

```
task example: :environment do
  Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].execute
end
```

When I run `rake db:populate:development`, all the tasks are run except for `Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].execute`. There's no activity in the development log for that command, but it doesn't prevent the next task from running (starting the server). Usually, I see some SQL statements when I run `db:test:prepare` by itself.

Notes:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.2

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

$ uname -a
Darwin hook 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the correct way of doing it, but I was having similar problems and ended up calling it using:

```
`rake db:test:prepare`
```

This is the only method that seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke` instead of `.execute`, so that it runs dependent tasks first. But it only invokes the task if its not invoked first.

Refer: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290119)

Answer (score 0):

The Rake task likely gets to this line https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L364 and `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` is blank.  This variable is set here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L5 (see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/370e1ad3f1f30f955bd781f0ecd113409b8ccf8f/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb#L21).

Is there a chance that your `database.yml` is missing the current environment or is something else clearing the configuration?

Comment: Good idea, but that's not it either. The `database.yml` is set up correctly and checking `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.blank?` in my custom rake task returns `false`.

Comment: Where are you placing the debug statement?  Could you try adding it immediately before line https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L364?

Comment: I just tried that and still got `false`. And with the debugger I was able to step through and confirm that it was entering the `unless` clause (and from there stepped into Rails internals that I don't quite understand).

Comment: I see. Could you include what the db:populate task does (perhaps it's this gem https://github.com/ffmike/db-populate)?

Another idea--could you call your example task that wraps db:test:prepare rather than use the task directly?  Not a great solution but at least it solves your problem!

Comment: My case actually isn't using `db:populate` at all (and doesn't have the gem installed). I'm doing a series of standard rake tasks (`db:drop`, `db:create`, etc).

Comment: And playing around with subtasks that call it might be another workaround, but I'm still curious why it doesn't work directly.