# How to call a rake task in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake, rspec-rails

I am trying to invoke a rake task in in my rspec.

```
  require "rake"
  rake = Rake::Application.new
  Rake.application = rake
  rake.init
  rake.load_rakefile
  rake['rake my:task'].invoke
```

But i am getting error

```
 Failure/Error: rake['rake db:migrate'].invoke
 RuntimeError:
   Don't know how to build task 'rake db:migrate'
```

Does anyone have a idea how we can invoke rake task in rspec code.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass in the arguments in square brackets to `invoke`:

```
rake sim:manual_review_referral_program[3,4]
```

becomes:

```
rake['sim:manual_review_referral_program'].invoke(3,4)
```

If your `args` are in an array, you can do the following:

```
args = [3,4]
rake['sim:manual_review_referral_program'].invoke(*args)
```

More info at this StackOverflow question: [How to run Rake tasks from within Rake tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks).

Answer (score 12):

Small namespacing issue, the task is `db:migrate` not `rake db:migrate` like the command line usage.

So changing it to this should help:

```
rake['db:migrate'].invoke
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work. Now I have my custom rake task that is define in 'lib/tasks/' folder. How can I run that from rspec ?

Comment: anything with a `.rake` extension in the `lib/tasks` folder will be included by default. Since your Rakefile probably came from rails the task should be loaded and available.

Comment: Getting below error Failure/Error: rake['sim:manual_review_referral_program[3]'].invoke
     RuntimeError:
       Don't know how to build task 'sim:manual_review_referral_program[3]'

Comment: I'm not sure the `[3]` is a valid name for a rake task.

Comment: its paramater to rake task "rake my:task[arg1,arg2]"

Answer (score 12):

A simpler solution for Rails with Rspec :

In your `spec_helper` (or `rails_helper` for newer versions of rspec-rails) :

```
require "rake"
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Then when you want to invoke your task you can do the following :

```
Rake::Task['my:task'].invoke
```