# Rspec fails with 'invalid option' even though the option is valid. Is this a bug in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, circleci

When I run `$ bundle exec rspec spec --format progress` it gives this error:

```
..*....invalid option: --format
F**..**..***................*.*********
```

Even though that's a valid option. When I run the test with `rspec` or `bundle exec rspec` then all tests pass. The test that fails is

```
  1) Refinery::PagesController get all the methods succeeds
     Failure/Error: rake.init
     SystemExit:
       exit
     # ./spec/controllers/refinery/pages_controller_spec.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The spec that fails is

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'refinery/pages_controller'
require "rake"

describe Refinery::PagesController do
  render_views
  
  before do 
...
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704976/how-to-call-a-rake-task-in-rspec
    rake = Rake::Application.new
    Rake.application = rake
    rake.init                         ### LINE 64
    rake.load_rakefile
    rake['categories:create'].invoke
```

Why don't I just run `rspec` command instead? Because CircleCI(.com - continuous integration server) is the one that sets the command line and we don't have control over that.

#### Versions

```
Rails 3.2.14

$ gem list rspec
rspec (2.14.1)
rspec-core (2.14.8, 2.14.7)
rspec-expectations (2.14.5, 2.14.4)
rspec-mocks (2.14.6, 2.14.4)
rspec-rails (2.14.2, 2.14.1)

Gemfile.lock:    rspec (2.14.1)
Gemfile.lock:    rspec-core (2.14.7)
Gemfile.lock:    rspec-expectations (2.14.4)
Gemfile.lock:    rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
Gemfile.lock:    rspec-rails (2.14.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for CircleCI and this came across my radar.

You can set custom test commands, including overriding Circle's built-in code/test inference, using your circle.yml file. In your case, setting something like:

```
test:
  override:
    - rspec
```

would fit the bill and would cause `rspec` to run instead of `bundle exec rspec spec --format progress`

Comment: Ok how can I re-run a test without checking out the code again? I want to SSH into the server and test it without having to commit each time I want to test.

Comment: Ok I think that will work. I also found I can type a command in the top box of https://circleci.com/gh/account/project/edit#tests. So now it passed!

Answer (score 2):

If your dependencies are managed with bundler you should go with:

```
test:
  override:
    - bundle exec rspec
```

so that your bundle is available

Comment: That's actually what I used.