# Rake/RSpec segmentation fault depends on Rake task format. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, segmentation-fault, rake

Having an "interesting" segfault with a `rake` task. When run **as quoted here** from the command line, it works properly. If I run all `rake` tasks from a single `system` call, I get a segfault.

```
task :cruise do
  system 'rake db:reset db:test:clone teabag'
  system 'rake spec'
end
```

For those of you unfamiliar with it, [Teabag](https://github.com/modeset/teabag) is "a JavaScript test runner built on top of Rails". So what we have here is basically:

1. Reinitialise the (development) database
2. Clone the test database from the known-state development one; and
3. Run specs for {Java,Coffee}Script and Ruby/Rails.

Version information:

- OS X 10.8.2
- ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
- **Not** using `rvm`
- Rails 3.2.12

My `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jdickey/5074510/edit). Task output, **including** crash dump, is [on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rGG8W9N5).

**EDITED 5 March 2013 12:20 SGT (GMT+8) ***

I rewrote the task as

```
task :cruise do
  ['db:reset', 'db:test:clone', 'teabag', 'spec'].each do |task|
    Rake::Task[task].reenable
    Rake::Task[task].invoke
  end
end
```

and it runs as expected. (Note that I had to add `Rake::Task[task].reenable` to eliminate the RSpec segfault).

This still doesn't answer why RSpec will reliably segfault when either run as part of a multi-task `rake` command line (as with the original `system`-calling task) or when run in the reworked `cruise` task without calling `reenable` before `invoke`.  But I've got the workaround, so I consider the question *answered*.

Comment: You should not use `system` to invoke a rake task from within another rake task. Use `Rake::Task['namespace:task'].invoke` instead. See this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/1290119/100466. See if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @waseem. You got me to where I needed to be, and I updated the main question text accordingly.