# rake argument for task group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

How can I pass an argument to a **group** of rake tasks?

I can pass an argument to each individual task (foo1, foo2):

```
desc "foo1"
task :foo1, [ :mode ] => :environment do |t, args|

  mode = args[:mode]
  puts "foo1 mode = #{mode}"

end

desc "foo2"
task :foo2, [ :mode ] => :environment do |t, args|

  mode = args[:mode]
  puts "foo2 mode = #{mode}"

end

desc "all_foos"
task :all_foos, [ :mode ] => [ :foo1, :foo2 ]
```

As you can see, foo1 and foo2 are grouped in all_foos. The all_foos task also accepts the mode argument, but I have no clue how to pass the mode argument to foo1 and foo2 in all_foos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the tasks from your all_foos task and pass in any args you want:

```
desc "all_foos"
task :all_foos, [ :mode ] => :environment do |task, args|
  Rake::Task['foo1'].invoke args[:mode]
  Rake::Task['foo2'].invoke args[:mode]
end
```

Here's more: [How to run Rake tasks from within Rake tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks)

Comment: Which tutorial you used to learn `Rake`. I am also learning `Rake`.

Comment: this is why i always like official documentation

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your code?

When I execute your code

```
require 'rake'

task :environment 

desc "foo1"
task :foo1, [ :mode ] => :environment do |t, args|

  mode = args[:mode]
  puts "foo1 mode = #{mode}"

end

desc "foo2"
task :foo2, [ :mode ] => :environment do |t, args|

  mode = args[:mode]
  puts "foo2 mode = #{mode}"

end

desc "all_foos"
task :all_foos, [ :mode ] => [ :foo1, :foo2 ]

Rake.application['all_foos'].invoke('par1')
```

I get

```
foo1 mode = par1
foo2 mode = par1
```

With

```
Rake.application['all_foos'].invoke('par2')
```

I get:

```
foo1 mode = par2
foo2 mode = par2
```

This is the solution you want.

Remark:
`Rake.application['all_foos'].invoke('par2')` is the same as an external rake call `rake all_foos[par2]`

---

To go further: You can also use different parameters.

CHeck this code:

```
require 'rake'

task :environment 

desc "foo1"
task :foo1, [ :mode1 ] => :environment do |t, args|

  mode = args[:mode1]
  puts "foo1 mode = #{mode}"

end

desc "foo2"
task :foo2, [ :mode2 ] => :environment do |t, args|

  mode = args[:mode2]
  puts "foo2 mode = #{mode}"

end

desc "all_foos"
task :all_foos, [ :mode1, :mode2 ] => [ :foo1, :foo2 ]

Rake.application['all_foos'].invoke('par1', 'par2')
```

With `Rake.application['all_foos'].invoke('par1', 'par2')` (or `rake all_foos[par1,par2]`) I get:

```
foo1 mode = par1
foo2 mode = par2
```

With `Rake.application['all_foos'].invoke('par1', 'par2')` (or `rake all_foos[par1,par2]`) I get:

```
foo1 mode = par1
foo2 mode = par2
```

With `Rake.application['all_foos'].invoke(nil, 'par2')` I get

```
foo1 mode = 
foo2 mode = par2
```

With `Rake.application['all_foos'].invoke('par1')` I get

```
foo1 mode = par1
foo2 mode =
```

If your main task contains all parameter names, you can pick the needed parameters in your subtasks.

Disadvantage: The sequence in the call differs between main task and subtasks.