# How can i add a task that will run after rake test:db:prepare in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using rails 4.2 and i am trying to run test using the command rake test.I am trying to use plv8 extention so i create it manually from psql console, then when i run the test it seems like it has deleted that extension from postgres. I looked into rails 4.2 project and i noticed that they brought test:db:prepare [back](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5c4495538bb4e8808ce077f08ea6b809952daa44). This is what is deleting the plv8 extension every time. how can i add a pice of code that will run after the test:db:prepare or test:db:create?

I am not a big fan of modifying Rakefile solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can name multiple tasks inline:

```
rake test:db:create test:db:prepare custom:task
```

Or when you create a new rake task you can make it dependent on any other task:

```
desc "the dependent task will run before this one"
task my_task: :other_task do
   # stuff
end
```

You can also arbitrarily invoke other tasks:

```
Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke
```

More info here: http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial and here: [How to run Rake tasks from within Rake tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks/1290119#1290119)