# Running Rake tasks in RSpec multiple times returns nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

I'm guessing this has to do with Rake reading the file once and not rewinding it? But, I'm not sure. Any ideas?

```
require 'rake'
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'MyRakeTask' do

  before(:all) do
    Rails.application.load_tasks
  end

  it 'does something sweet' do
    Rake::Task["namespace:my_task"].invoke # runs task
  end

  it 'but it doesnt do it again' do
    Rake::Task["namespace:my_task"].invoke # returns nil
  end

end
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [Rake](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/Task.html#method-i-invoke) docs say `invoke` will only run the task if it's "needed". The following was pulled from another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks) and might help clarify:

- **Rake::Task["build"].execute** always executes the task, but it doesn't execute its dependencies
- **Rake::Task["build"].invoke** executes the dependencies, but it only executes the task if
  it has not already been invoked
- **Rake::Task["build"].reenable** first resets the task's already_invoked state, allowing the task to then be executed again, dependencies and all.

Comment: Thank you!! The `reenable` was what did it.

Comment: This is handy (`.reenable`) when one task invokes another task. (Not the best design perhaps, but it is what it is) This works fine in the real world, where the other task has never been run. But in rspec, the other task is very likely already run in another test, so won't run when re-invoked by another task. I could have reenabled it in rspec, but it felt cleaner (and mostly harmless) to do it directly in the task code.