# How to invoke RSpec inside a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

We wrote some tests that are necessary, but very slow. So we configured RSpec to exclude them except on Solano, where we set up an ENV variable.

```
# spec_helper
unless ENV['RUN_ALL_TESTS'] == 'true'
  config.filter_run_excluding :slow
end
```

That works, but I'm trying to write a rake task we can call to run every test locally by setting that same ENV variable and then running the suite. I'm having trouble figuring out how to trigger RSpec. This is what I've got now:

```
# all_tests.rake
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc 'Run all tests, even those usually excluded.'
task all_tests: :environment do
  ENV['RUN_ALL_TESTS'] = 'true'
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
end
```

When I run it, it doesn't run any tests.

Most of the stuff I found is for triggering a rake task inside of a test, testing a rake task, or setting up a Rakefile. We're using `rspec-rails`, our default rake task is already set up.

Comment: sounds like you're after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks

Comment: That definitely looks like what I'm after, but I'm still missing something because `Rake::Task['spec'].invoke` and `Rake::Task['default'].invoke` still do nothing.

Comment: Have you tried just `RUN_ALL_TESTS=true rake spec` ?

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'd still love to figure out how to call this inside of a rake task, if anyone has any more suggestions. I was able to successfully invoke other rake tasks using the method from the link, but `Rake::Task['spec'].invoke` returns nil, and `Rake::Task['default'].invoke` just returns `"test"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run RSpec through its rake integration, you need to both define a task and invoke it:

```
# all_tests.rake
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

# Define the "spec" task, at task load time rather than inside another task
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

desc 'Run all tests, even those usually excluded.'
task all_tests: :environment do
  ENV['RUN_ALL_TESTS'] = 'true'
  Rake::Task['spec'].invoke
end
```

`Rake::Task['spec'].invoke` did nothing when you tried it because rake turns a task name which is not a name of a defined task but is a file name into a [`Rake::FileTask`](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/file_task.rb), both on the command line and in `Rake::Task`. You had no `'spec'` task defined, but you have a `spec` directory, so `rake spec` ran without error and did nothing.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where `bundle exec rake default` would properly create an `RSpec::Core::RakeTask`, but `bundle exec rake spec` would instead create a a `Rake::FileTask` on the `spec` directory, with with `bundle exec rake spec --trace` outputting:

```
** Invoke spec (first_time, not_needed)
```

It turned out that `rspec-rails` was in the `:test` gem group, where it needed ([per the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs)) to be in both `:test` and `:development`.

Interestingly (?), once I did that, gems that had previously only been in the `:test` group were also available from the specs even when launched with `RAILS_ENV=development`. I assume that `rspec-rails` engages in some magic environment shenanigans behind the scenes.

Comment: (Noting this as an answer here because it's the only place I've seen the `spec` → `FileTask` problem discussed on StackOverflow.)