# Running rake multitask on another rake task in parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parallel-processing, rake

I'm attempting to setup a Ruby rake task that I usually split into 2 parts manually (ie. run in two separate tabs) as one parallelized rake task, running as `rake parallel:main` seen here:

```
namespace :parallel do
  multitask main: [:job1, :job2]

  task :job1 => :environment do
    companies = (34320..34330).to_a

    companies.each do |c|
      puts "Running on company #{c} - #{Time.now}"

      Rake::Task['parallel:my_task'].invoke("#{c}")
      Rake::Task['parallel:my_task'].reenable
    end
  end

  task :job2 => :environment do
    companies = (34340..34350).to_a

    companies.each do |c|
      puts "Running on company #{c} - #{Time.now}"

      Rake::Task['parallel:my_task'].invoke("#{c}")
      Rake::Task['parallel:my_task'].reenable
    end
  end

  task :my_task, [:c] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts "Processing #{args[:c]} - #{Time.now}"
    sleep 5
  end
end
```

I can see that the `Time.now` from within these job tasks are run in parallel, but based on `Time.now` output from within `my_task` I can see that the underlying rake task is not run in parallel.

This is what the output looks like:

```
$ rake parallel:main
Running on company 34320 - 2017-06-15 14:15:17 -0400
Running on company 34340 - 2017-06-15 14:15:17 -0400
Processing 34320 - 2017-06-15 14:15:17 -0400
Processing 34340 - 2017-06-15 14:15:22 -0400
Running on company 34321 - 2017-06-15 14:15:22 -0400
Running on company 34341 - 2017-06-15 14:15:27 -0400
Processing 34321 - 2017-06-15 14:15:27 -0400
Running on company 34342 - 2017-06-15 14:15:32 -0400
Processing 34342 - 2017-06-15 14:15:32 -0400
Running on company 34322 - 2017-06-15 14:15:32 -0400
```

As you can see, the first `Processing` happens at 14:15:17, and the second at 14:15:22, based on the sleep. I'd like these to run simultaneously - how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I just learnt that `invoke` executes the dependencies, but it only executes the task if it has not already been invoked ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577944/how-to-run-rake-tasks-from-within-rake-tasks?rq=1)).

So I changed my code to the following and it works well:
`Rake::Task['parallel:my_task'].execute :c => c`